# Modified intersection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the below modified intersection defined as follows:

$$A \hat{\cap} B := (A\cap B) \text{ if dim}(A\cap B) = \text{min}(\text{dim}, (A),\text{dim}(B)), \emptyset \text{ otherwise} $$

Where A and B be compact sets and dim(A) is the cardinality of the basis needed to span the smallest vector space containing A.

I was just wondering if this function already has a name/where I could read up about it being used if it has been used before.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? If just  sets, how do you define the dimension of a set???

Comment: Apologies, let A and B be compact sets and dim(A) be the cardinality of the basis needed to span the smallest vector space containing A.

Comment: E.g. if for all $u,v,w \in A$, $u,v$ and $w$ are coplanar then the smallest vector space containing all $u \in A$ is a plane and must therefore have a basis of 2 vectors - thus A has dimension 2.